# Why if I input EOF from keyboard Clion don't print on Run window the output of the program?

Tags: c++, clion

I just start to using Clion as my IDE and I'm struggling with EOF inputed from keyboard.
If I execute this simple c++ code

```
 #include <iostream>

int main(){
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    //read until EOF, calculating a running total of all values read
    while(std::cin >> value){
        sum += value;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum is " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the Run window of Clion, after I input from keyboard
`1 2 cmd+d` I get this

```
1 2 ^D

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704) with CLion on Windows. Disabling the run.processes.with.pty in Registry (open via Find Action) usually helps.

Comment: Thanks! This workaround solved my issue, but please notice that I'm on MacOS version of Clion.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue in 2024. What does disabling 'run.processes.with.pty' do? Will disabling it affect any functionalities?

Comment: Disabling 'run.processes.with.pty' in the Registry enables EOF but affects functions like scanf and fgets, causing them to block prints and other functions before them.
Check this thread: ```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/61486359/19975267
```

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS the EOF(with keyboard) is Cmd+D. 
In CLion is in settable in:

> File -> Preferences -> KeyMap -> search EOF and set Cmd+D.

---

However, I suggest you to use in your code a **Terminating Character** such as zero that in [this](http://cpp.sh/2obcl) case doesn't change the result.

[Example of execution in CLion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Weg.png)

Answer (score 1):

In some environments the EOF emulation is performed using Ctrl+Z combination not Ctrl+D

To avoid such problems - create file with contents you want to enter "1 2"

and run your program from terminal redirecting the standard input to read from file. In this case the EOF event will always happen at the end of the input.

```
$./test < myinputfile.txt
```