# CLion workaround made bug worse

Tags: c, mingw, clion, c99, jetbrains-ide

There's this bug with the placement of certain characters in the embedded terminal in CLion (more thoroughly explained [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-19357) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-17579)) and there's this workaround, by disabling PTY (Help | Find Action > type "Registry" > open Registry > find and disable the run.processes.with.pty option).

The problem is that this, for me, breaks the program completely. If there's even a single scanf in the code, it does nothing until you introduce some kind of data for that scanf (it doesn't even do printf lines that are BEFORE the scanf, and only does them after you introduce the scanf data).

Why does this happen, and is there also an workaround for this or am I stuck with bad character placement?

Thank you,
José Almeida

Comment: Are you saying, `scanf` shouldn't block?

Comment: No. I'm saying it blocks things >before< it. Like:
printf("Hello");
scanf("%d", &test);
printf("No");

Should print Hello, then wait for input, then print No. With PTY disabled, it waits for input first, then writes "Hello" and "No" at the same time

Comment: Put a newline at the end: `printf("hello\n")` or use `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`.

Comment: The \n technique doesn't work, but the fflush one does. Why though? Will I have to do this every time i use a printf and a scanf? This is counterproductive

Comment: `stdout` is line buffered. So everything you print stays in memory until 1) a newline is printed, 2) fflush is called, or 3) an input function (like `scanf`) is called. Those are the rules according to the C standard. I'm guessing the workaround disables 1 and 3, so you're left with 2.

Comment: okay, thanks for the explanation. I'll look at other potentian workarounds to the initial bug

Comment: Same here.

I disabled "run.processes.with.pty" in Registry for EOF to work. Check this: ```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45820377/19975267
```

But now scanf and fgets(stdin-related functions) blocks prints & other functions before them...